# Convert list to list of quarters using LinQ

Tags: linq, list

I  am having a list of Item : `List<Item>`
I want to convert it to list of `Items + quarters -> list<ItemModel>`

Item also contains another list i.e. ItemDetails.

How to copy Item object to another Item object and retrieve quarter from CreatedDate using LinQ?

I have also added Quarter structure for converting Date to quarter. But I am unable to convert `list<Item>` to `list<ItemModel>`

```
class Item{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<NameValuePair> ItemDetails { get; set; }
    }


 public struct Quarter
    {
        public Quarter(int year, int quarterIndex)
        {
            Year = year;
            QuarterIndex = quarterIndex;
        }

        public static Quarter FromDate(DateTime date)
        {
            return new Quarter(date.Year, 1 + (date.Month - 1) / 3);
        }

        public int Year;
        public int QuarterIndex;
    }

 public class ItemModel
 {
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public Quarter Quarter { get; set; }
 }
```

Can you please help me with it?

Comment: First thing I'd suggest: make your `Quarter` struct immutable, and keep the fields private. (Expose properties instead.) Next, implement `IEquatable<Quarter>` and `IComparable<Quarter>`.

Comment: It's not clear why you need an `ItemModel` type at all, by the way. Can't you just add a readonly `Quarter` property to `Item` which is implemented by calling `Quarter.FromDate(CreatedDate)`?

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: No, because it's not clear how useful it would be... and you should be able to add it yourself pretty easily. Which part of what I've suggested are you finding hard to implement?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert `List<Item>` to `List<ItemModel>`, but you can create a new list:

```
List<Item> itemList = ...;
List<ItemModel> itemModelList = itemList
    .Select(item => new ItemModel { Item = item, Quarter = Quarter.FromDate(item.CreatedDate)})
    .ToList();
```